# Nullpointer when testing components in springBoot 2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit, junit4

I have a SpringBoot 2 app with this component

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class RequestHostelUtils {

    private RequestHostelUtils() {
        // Private constructor to hide the implicit public one
    }
```

and this other one

```
@Component
public class RequestEntityPredicates {

    private final RequestHostelUtils requestHostelUtils;

    public RequestEntityPredicates(RequestHostelUtils requestHostelUtils) {
        this.requestHostelUtils = requestHostelUtils;
    }
```

and this Unit Test, that when I test it I git a nullpointer in requestEntityPredicates because requestHostelUtils is null;

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@Slf4j
    public class RequestEntityValidatorsTests {

        @Autowired
        private RequestHostelUtils requestHostelUtils;

        private RequestEntityPredicates requestEntityPredicates;



    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        requestEntityPredicates = new RequestEntityPredicates(requestHostelUtils);
    }
```

I also tried

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class })
@Slf4j
 public class RequestEntityValidatorsTests {
```

with the same results

Comment: You are running your class with `MockitoJunitRunner` which doesn't know anything about Spring. Hence nothing will be injected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your beans into Spring:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { RequestHostelUtils.class, RequestEntityPredicates.class })
@Slf4j
public class RequestEntityValidatorsTests {
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to autowire your Bean. Add `@Autowired` to your ctor like this:

```
@Component
public class RequestEntityPredicates {

    private final RequestHostelUtils requestHostelUtils;

    @Autowired
    public RequestEntityPredicates(RequestHostelUtils requestHostelUtils) {
        this.requestHostelUtils = requestHostelUtils;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't think so, since I use Constructor injection